# Linking a DLL to a Python extension when filename does not match the library name

Tags: python, windows, numpy, gfortran

Is it possible to change the assembly name of a DLL after it has been compiled and linked? If so what tool should I use to do this? I've failed in my searches for the answer, likely because I don't know enough about the subject.

I have been provided DLLs that I am linking to a Python extension on Windows generated with numpy.distutils and F2PY wrappers. I am using the MinGW-w64 tools and gfortran as the compiler. The DLLs were also compiled with gfortran. The extension compiles and links just fine with, however at runtime I get the error  `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` Using dependency walker I was able to discover that the library name is in fact different from the file name. I can change the file name to match the library name dependency walker reports, but name contains metadata the individual used ot track their projects, e.g. 'mylib-v4-fix'. I would like to modify the library name to be consistent with the file name of the DLL, e.g 'mylib.dll'. I was not provided .lib or .def files, but presumably I could create these if necessary.

Comment: You can always change the code inside (not assembly, but machine code) that's what crackers or viruses do.  Just open a byte editor. The problem is how to change those bytes so that it wil work as desired and that is impossible to say without details.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a shot, but it's going to be more trouble than it's worth to get it right. It was easy enough to change a couple characters, but removing characters is beyond me at this point. I think I'll deal with the ugly names until I can get it fixed.